# Pygame - Issue Altering x Value While event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a snake game, and I'm trying to get the snake `rect` to keep moving while `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN`.  I can get the block to move on `KEYDOWN`, but it doesn't continue to move by updating the `lead_x` value for the `rect`.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit = False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -10
                lead_x_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = 10
                lead_x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            lead_y_change = 0
            lead_x_change = 0

        print(event)
        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.fill(black, rect=[lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
        gameDisplay.fill(red, rect=[200,200,10,10])
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have put the games loop code inside the event handler. Remove an indent from each line between lead_x += lead_x_change and clock.tick(15) inclusive

I would also remove the lines

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    lead_y_change = 0
    lead_x_change = 0
```

as they will stop the lead from moving if you move your mouse.